# Google map v2 marker not starting with my location

Tags: android, google-maps, location, android-maps-v2

```
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        googleMap = fm.getMap();

        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                  .position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()))
                  .title("Me")
                  .snippet("Population: 776733"));
```

When I run the code,google map is supposed to show the place where I am with the marker,but the map is opening up with some other place,no my current location,and I have to move to my location manually to find the marker.

Comment: use animateCamera or moveCamera to move the screen to the location you received which is the marker

Answer (score 1):

You should `animateCamera` on that particular location `Marker` like

```
LatLng current_loc= new LatLng(lat, lng);
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(current_loc, 18.0f));
```

For more information go to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views#moving_the_camera

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(your latitude, you longitude)));
```